# Access to iOS device's console output

Tags: ios, debugging, nslog, console-output

Is there an iOS app which allows to look at console output created by another iOS app?

My app has several NSLog() calls which output precise timings. I would like to test the app, when it **is not connected** to my development Mac, and look at timings after that, possibly still on my iDevice using some other "console browser" app.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

So the way to do this is to use the [Apple System Logger](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html) which allows you to access the logs and you can then display them on screen. NSLog will be logged to this. I wrote something a few years ago so that testers could test the app and open the log and view it on the device.

Its a bit tricky to use the interface and there is a limit, I think it was 200, on the number of logs in the cache, so log only the necessary stuff.

After a quick search, I found this - [SOLogger](https://github.com/billgarrison/SOLogger) which should help you.